# How to send request POST with correct content type (list of items)?

Tags: python, list, request

I have a question, in order not to add oil changes in the car via the website, I decided to write a program.
Theoretically, I have everything ready, but I don't quite know how to send the date correctly in POST.
When adding oil and brake pads replacement via the website, it is performed as follows:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: < coookies! >
Host:
Origin:
Referer:
Sec-Fetch-Dest:empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode:cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:same-origin
Sec-Gpc:1
User-Agent:Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

Form data:
bio: test car
owner: OneMan
changed:[{"changed":"oil","mil":127732}, {"changed":"breakpads","mil":126876}]
```

simple code:

```
import requests
import json

l = [{"changed":"oil","mil":127732},
     {"changed":"breakpads","mil":126876}]

datas = {
    'owner': 'someowner',
    'bio': 'bio',
    'changed':l
}

r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data=datas)
print(r.text)
```

Output:

```
"form": {
    "bio": "bio", 
    "changed": [
      "changed", 
      "mil", 
      "changed", 
      "mil"
    ], 
    "owner": "someowner"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Content-Length": "79", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.31.0", 
  }, 
  "json": null,  
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Changed not have values... Should be:

```
"form": {
    "bio": "bio", 
    "changed": [{"changed":"oil","mil":127732}, {"changed":"breakpads","mil":126876}], 
    "owner": "someowner"
  },
```

I tried also json=datas but the Content-Type (application/json) differs from the type sent by the browser(application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

```
 "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Content-Length": "125", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.31.0", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-654567c5-1e41b90071ba16fb763f73ab"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "bio": "bio", 
    "changed": [
      {
        "changed": "oil", 
        "mil": 127732
      }, 
      {
        "changed": "breakpads", 
        "mil": 126876
      }
    ], 
    "owner": "someowner"
  }, 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
```

How correct send this request with `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and double ( not single) quotes like original browser request?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to convert `l` to JSON format.

```
datas = {
    'owner': 'someowner',
    'bio': 'bio',
    'changed': json.dumps(l)
}
```